# Extreme value theorem for the non euclidean topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If we had a continuous mapping from a compact topological space U to R, but R is not endowed with the Euclidean topology, does the function still attain its maximum value? Compactness is still preserved by f so the image of R is still a compact set. If we endow R with the discrete topology then, the image of f would be a set of finite points because only finite sets are compact under the discrete topology and one of those points would be the maximum. But if R is endowed with any arbitrary topology, is this always true? There are topologies out there where closed and bounded does not imply compact even if we are working with R such as the cofinite topology.

Also, one thing I have been wondering for a while is: did we implicitly assume that we are always working with the Euclidean topology when we were studying basic real analysis? R would not have the least upper bound property if we worked on some other topology right? Under any non Hausdorff topology, even sequence convergence would not make any sense so every single real analysis theorem would  pretty much fail.

Comment: In analysis, you are working with the metric structure of $\mathbb{R}$, hence the usual topology. That’s what all those $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are: the radius of balls giving basic open sets. Endow $\mathbb{R}$ with the indiscrete topology, and every subset is compact, every function is continuous, so it would certainly not have the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we had a continuous mapping from a compact topological space U to R, but R is not endowed with the Euclidean topology, does the function still attain its maximum value?

No, not necessarily. First of all the antidiscrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ makes all functions $U\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous, regardless of whether they achieve maximum or not. But even if our new topology is extremely nice, e.g. homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, this still may not be true.

First define $\tau_{E}$ to be the standard Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a bijection such that $f([0,1])=(0,1)$. Such bijection exists since $[0,1]$, $(0,1)$ and their complements are all of the same cardinality. Then define a new topology on $\mathbb{R}$ by defining $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ to be open if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\tau_E$. Denote this topology by $\tau'$. This makes $f:(\mathbb{R},\tau_E)\to(\mathbb{R},\tau')$ a homeomorphism. Note that our $f$ preserves topology but breaks ordering.

Now let $i:([0,1], \tau_E)\to(\mathbb{R},\tau_E)$ be the standard inclusion $i(x)=x$. Compose that map with $f$ to obtain a continous map $([0,1],\tau_E)\to(\mathbb{R},\tau')$ whose image is $(0,1)$ and thus it does not attain maximum.

The only reason continuity is related to maximum in the Euclidean case is because the Euclidean topology arises from the ordering to begin with.

> Also, one thing I have been wondering for a while is: did we implicitly assume that we are always working with the Euclidean topology when we were studying basic real analysis?

Typicaly yes, unless explicitly stated otherwise.